# What is stopping this program from having an output

Tags: c#, list

I made this code to brute force anagrams by printing all possible permutables of the characters in a string, however there is no output. I do not need simplifications as I am a student still learning the basics, I just need help getting it to work this way so I can better understand it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace anagramSolver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter anagram:");
            string anagram = Console.ReadLine();
            string temp = "";

            List<string> storeStr = new List<string>(0);
            List<int> storeInt = new List<int>(0);

            //creates factorial number for anagram
            int factorial = 1;
            for (int i = anagram.Length; i > 0; i--)
            {
                factorial *= i;
            }



            while (storeStr.Count != factorial)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                while(temp.Length != anagram.Length)
                {
                    int num = rnd.Next(anagram.Length - 1);
                    if (storeInt.Contains(num) == true)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storeInt.Add(num);
                        temp += anagram[num];
                    } 
                }
                if (storeStr.Contains(temp) == true)
                {
                    temp = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    storeStr.Add(temp);
                    Console.WriteLine(temp, storeStr.Count);
                    temp = "";
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit: added temp reset after it is deemed contained by storeStr

Comment: your program does not stop, does it ? seems you have an infinite loop (by quickly executing it with a short word like "test").

Comment: seems that way @Pac0, im just not sure why

Comment: Not answering directly, I'd recommend this reading : https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , at least for the principal and "general culture". In particular, I'd recommend that you use the visual studio (or whatever IDE) debugger, use breakpoints and go step by step, and "watch" some variables to make sure it does what you think your algorithm is supposed to do. You can also add some more Console.WriteLine to "trace" the flow of your code. You have some branching (if else), and it will be useful to see what is happening. That's what I'm gonna do in an online ide now.

Comment: Hint: use simple input to test your program. With "a" as input, it outputs "a" and stops. However, with "ab", it goes into loop already.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/kebo4j-gw

Comment: Also try to break down the parts of your program. I'd recommend trying out just the random number parts. Check the documentation for Random.Next, I don't think you should use -1. It's not the only problem, though. The first iteration goes well if you remove the -1. However, you don't reset storeInt.

Comment: strong recommendation, put the `new Random` outside the loop, only call it once

Comment: @DinoDini Your answer was not related to either of the infinite loops in the question, so it was not an answer to the question that was asked. That's why it got downvoted. Help is appreciated, and your point was correct, it just didn't address the actual errors in the program.

Comment: I know you're just looking for help getting your program working, but you really should consider a better algorithm. You're trying to randomly generate all possible permutations when there's an elegant and straightforward method of generating all of them You should read Eric Lippert's excellent series about permutations, starting with Part 1. https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: thanks @JimMischel, ill give it a read. and thanks everyone for all the help, ive learned a lot about debugging, and got my program working.

Comment: Side note: Factorial is generally negative (for n > 17) and become 0 for most numbers (starting 35). You really don't want to use that as end of the loop for correctness (absolutely non-practical restriction in reality).

Answer (score 2):

Two main issues causing infinite loop:

1)

As per [`Random.Next documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0#system-random-next(system-int32)), the parameter is the "exclusive" upper bound. This means, if you want a random number between 0 and anagram.Length - 1 included, you should use `rnd.Next(anagram.Length);`.

With `rnd.Next(anagram.Length - 1)`, you'll never hit `anagram.Length - 1`.

2)

Even if you solve 1, only the first main iteration goes well.

`storeInt` is never reset. Meaning, after the first main iteration, it will have already all the numbers in it.

So, during the second iteration, you will always hit the case `if (storeInt.Contains(num) == true)`, which does nothing and the inner loop will go on forever.

Comment: Nice, you found both of the problems. Now try your program out with one or more duplicate characters. And yes, I do have the heart of a sadist... I mean teacher. :P

Comment: yep.... but the answer is an another castle, err, question !

Answer (score 2):

Several issues here...

The expression `rnd.Next(anagram.Length - 1)` generates a value between 0 and `anagram.Length - 2`. For an input with two characters it will always return 0, so you'll never actually generate a full string. Remove the `- 1` from it and you'll be fine.

Next, you're using a list to keep track of the character indices you've used already, but you never clear the list. You'll get one output (eventually, when the random number generator covers all the values) and then enter an infinite loop on the next generation pass. Clear `storeInt` after the generation loop to fix this.

While not a true infinite loop, creating a new instance of the random number generator each time will give you a lot of duplication. `new Random()` uses the current time as a seed value and you could potentially get through a ton of loops with each seed, generating exactly the same values until the time changes enough to change your random sequence. Create the random number generator once before you start your main loop.

And finally, your code doesn't handle repeated input letters. If the input is "aa" then there is only a single distinct output, but your code won't stop until it gets two. If the input was "aab" there are three distinct permutations ("aab", "aba", "baa") which is half of the expected results. You'll never reach your exit condition in this case. You could do it by keeping track of the indices you've used instead of the generated strings, it just makes it a bit more complex.

There are a few ways to generate permutations that are less error-prone. In general you should try to avoid "keep generating random garbage until I find the result I'm looking for" solutions. Think about how you personally would go about writing down the full list of permutations for 3, 4 or 5 inputs. What steps would you take? Think about how that would work in a computer program.

Answer (score -1):

this loop

```
           while(temp.Length != anagram.Length)
            {
                int num = rnd.Next(anagram.Length - 1);
                if (storeInt.Contains(num) == true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    storeInt.Add(num);
                    temp += anagram[num];
                } 
            }
```

gets stuck.

once the number is in storeInt you never change storeStr, yet thats what you are testing for loop exit

Comment: `storeStr` is a list of generated values, `temp` is added to in the next part of the outer loop. The more important part in this loop is that the `storeInt` list is never cleared.